# Can I change the axis of rotation of the joints from urdf file?

Tags: urdf, joint, rotation

I have a custom robot that is exported from fusion 360. In fusion I have no problems about the rotation of the joints. However when I export it to ros2 and use setup_assistant of the moveit2. The axis of rotation are different than 3D drawing. I would like to change them from the urdf file. Is there a way to this?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can modify it from its URDF file. Look for the *joint* tag:

```
<joint name="your_joint_name" ...>
...
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
...
</joint>
```

Modify the value of `axis` tag and `origin` tag as you wish. Refer to the [URDF joint documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint) for their meanings.

Comment: What does rpy change in the origin xyz?

Comment: Do you mean what rpy does in the origin tag?
rpy stands for roll pitch yaw and sets the initial angle of the joint name.

If you are still confused about this, I recommend you watch this first: [link](https://youtu.be/-fMxgG1cPDA?t=374) .
You don't have to watch all the video to understand the joint concept.

Comment: You can also look at the URDF documentation on the edited answer above for a more detailed information